# Creating an interactable grid with CSS and HTML ONLY on a single image

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary, grid

I am in the process of setting up a website via Enjin's web hosting for a game server I run. I have an HTML module that will display a map of the island our game server takes place on, with a grid overlay already.

What I am trying to do (if possible), is to create a dynamic grid with css and html (javascript if needed) that overlays the grid of the image and highlights each cell as a user hovers over it, with a small pop-up with details on a specific coordinate (such as any bases, or other special information about a specific area)

I have tried looking around via google, but all searches come up with creating a grid out of multiple images (which is not what I am after), or using the area tag without much explanation on how to turn it into a fullout grid.

I am unfamiliar with how to approach this problem, and would like any input or advice if possible. Thanks!

NOTE: For those wishing to see the map in question I am using, to better help understand my question and assist me, please see [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.enjin.com/1405090/ARK_MAP.jpg).

Comment: Yeah you could just use the image as the background of some element, then put the grid on top and when you hover each element over the grid, it displays some hidden info in that piece of the grid. Is that what you want?

Comment: Have you googled/tried using html `<map>`? You can target coordinates on the image area and assign placeholders/popovers/etc to each coordinate point.

Comment: Both ideas sound good. No I haven't tried googling the html map element, didn't even know there was one. Thanks for that tip. As for the grid idea, I'm assuming you mean like create a table with the image as the background?